# OpenCv in android ndk

Tags: opencv, android-ndk

I'm very new to Android development. 
I have written a desktop application in C/C++ that uses some OpenCV functions. Now I want to port this application into android.

Now if I want to use those same cpp files(which uses opencv library), how should I compile them. Where should I include openCV library for cpp.

I have downloaded and included opencv library for android but I directly want to use those cpp  files using android-ndk.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this document "[Android Development with OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html)" ? You can compile your cpp files using Android NDK with like this [Android.mk](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/blob/master/Chapter1_AndroidCartoonifier/Cartoonifier_Android/jni/Android.mk). I recommend you to read [Mastering OpenCV with Practical Computer Vision Projects](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code) or such kind of Book.